# How to search in sqlite by date?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, datetime, android-date

I'm saving im my table a colum current_date in this format: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'

How to search in database by date? I want, for examble the records from 2013-09-25 discarting the hour.

If I do this "Select current_date from mydatabase where current_date = '2013-09-25'" 
It does not work. I have to make this "Select current_date from mydatabase where current_date = '2013-09-25 09:25'". But i want only the record based on the date, not based on the date and hour.

Comment: Have you tried saying `WHERE SUBSTR(current_date, 1, 10) = '2013-09-25'`?

Comment: This SUBSTR works in SQLite?

Comment: http://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your dates are stored as Strings. You can use LIKE to discard the hour :

```
 select current_date from mydatabase where current_date like '2013-09-25%'
```

Comment: how can I do this on rawQuery?    'rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs'

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM mydatabase WHERE ( current_date > '2011-08-07') AND (current_date < '2011-08-08')
```

Replace the first date with the day you want information about and then update the second date with the following day.

Comment: backticks are so MySQL

Comment: With a normal (case-sensitive) index, this can be better optimized than LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use date function of sqlite

```
Select current_date from mydatabase where date(current_date) = '2013-09-25'
```

instead of

```
Select current_date from mydatabase where current_date = '2013-09-25'
```

Extra:-
If you want to fetch using time then you can also do that using time function

```
Select current_date from mydatabase where time(current_date) = '09:25'
```